# IOS - set UIImage on UIView half outside

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

[image]

I am trying to set this "Thump image" on UIView which should be half outside the to that view as shown in the image. So should I use coreGraphics framework or some other thing.

Comment: if your 'imageView' is inside the 'UIVIew' then don't forget to assign 'clipsToBound' property to 'false'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add UIImageView inside UIView ,it doesn't matter if it is outside the bounds of UIView. You just have to make sure that UIViews clipToBounds property false. But portion of the UIImgeView that is outsitside UIView is not interactable.

Comment: Thanks buddy such a simple logic i need to work hard :) Keep it up. And clipToBounds is by default set No

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect screenRectSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
//create a one view with the size of screen Size
UIView* transparentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRectSize];
// add the background color to black and the opacity to 0.6
 transparentView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
// add this to main view 
[self.view addSubview:transparentView];


// create the one UIview for white Box

 UIView* whiteView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,300,300)];
 whiteView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor] ;
// add this to main view 
[transparentView addSubview:whiteView];


// create the one UIview for white Box

 UIView* ImageViewbackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,whiteView.frame.origin.y-150,150,150)]; // this is important - whiteView.frame.origin.y-150
ImageViewbackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor] ;
// add this to main view 
 ImageViewbackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = ImageViewbackgroundView.frame.size.Width /2;
ImageViewbackgroundView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[transparentView addSubview:ImageViewbackgroundView];


// create the Imageview 
UIImageView *thumb =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(ImageViewbackgroundView.frame.origin.x+10,ImageViewbackgroundView.frame.origin.y+10,ImageViewbackgroundView.frame.size.width-10,ImageViewbackgroundView.frame.size.height-10)]; // customize your Frame
thumb.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimageName.png"];
 thumb.layer.cornerRadius = thumb.frame.size.Width /2;
 thumb.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[ImageViewbackgroundView addSubview:thumb];
```

**Additional**

add tapgesture for remove transparent view, like

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = 
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                      action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[transparentView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];


- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

 [transparentView removefromsuperview];
}
```

Comment: Thank You @Anbu I will definitely try this tommorrow and let you know

Comment: @DarshanMothreja -- I added the entire code, check once, if you need any help related to this I will explain.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a UIView with clear backgroundcolor (blue border) and place the other views inside. [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is some code using AutoLayout. You probably want to crate a dialog class subclassing UIView.

```
UIImageView *thumb =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
thumb.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dummy"];
thumb.layer.cornerRadius = 50;
thumb.clipsToBounds = YES;
UIView *dialog = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
dialog.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[dialog addSubview:thumb];
[thumb setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[dialog setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:dialog];
NSLayoutConstraint *dialogHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:dialog attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:200];
NSLayoutConstraint *dialogWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:dialog attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:200];
NSLayoutConstraint *thumbHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:thumb attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:100];
NSLayoutConstraint *thumbWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:thumb attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:100];
NSLayoutConstraint *thumbCenterX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:thumb attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:dialog attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *thumbCenterY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:thumb attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:dialog attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:-80];
NSLayoutConstraint *dialogCenterX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:dialog attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *dialogCenterY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:dialog attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0];
[thumb addConstraints:@[thumbHeight, thumbWidth]];
[dialog addConstraints:@[dialogHeight, dialogWidth, thumbCenterX, thumbCenterY]];
[self.view addConstraints:@[dialogCenterX, dialogCenterY]];
```

[image: Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

1. Take first view as rectangle base view
2. Take second view as square base for imageview, half outside. Add UIImage view as subview on 2nd view. Take outlet of second view.
3. In view did load method add code `secondView.layer.cornerRadius = secondView.frame.size.width/2.0;`